# How to drop elements in an array

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting

I have an array:

```
output = [["efg\r\n", "abc\r\n", "xyz\r\n", "mno\r\n", "end "]]
```

I need to sort and list something like below dropping the first and the last entries and getting rid of `"\r"` and `"\n"`.

```
abc 
xyz
mno
```

I tried using `pop` and `drop`, but they are not helping as this whole line is treated as first array (for example: `output[1][0]` will give `"efg\r\n"`).

Answer (score 3):

You need something linke

```
a = output[0][1,outputs.size-2].map{|t| t.strip}
```

Now a will be an array of the type `["abc", "xyz", "mno"]`. I did not sort this array as it does not seem to be sorted in the output you show.

Answer (score 1):

You can write that way:

```
output = arr.flatten[1..-1].map { |s| s.strip }.sort
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll bite:

```
output = [["efg\r\n", "abc\r\n", "xyz\r\n", "mno\r\n", "end "]]
output[0][1..-2].map &:strip
#=> ["abc", "xyz", "mno"]
```